# How to make two legends using ggplot 2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am rather new to plotting graphs in R. I'm trying to create two legends similar to the picture below. The picture below is of data from the previous year and I'm updating it but need to rewrite the code. So far my data looks identical to the bottom one (with updated data) except that the horizontal lines are not showing up in the legend. However, I need to make two legends as shown below but only have the Year part set up and am getting confused how to change both the name, line type and color of the lines while separating them into a separate legend from the Year Group.

Example of my data:

```
# Groups:   Year [6]
Year  Month  Temp
<fct> <ord> <dbl>
1 2014  Mar    14.9
2 2014  Apr    16.6
3 2014  May    20.5
4 2014  Jun    22.0
5 2014  Jul    23.9
6 2014  Aug    24.3
7 2014  Sep    24.4
8 2014  Oct    22.1
9 2014  Dec    13.6
10 2015  Jan    11.5
# ... with 46 more rows
```

My code so far:

```
 ggplot(wq4, aes(x=Month,y=Temp, color = Year)) +
 geom_line(aes(color = Year, group = Year)) + 
 labs(y = "Average Temperature (C)") +
 geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 5), color = "red", linetype="dashed") +
 geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 15), color = "dark green", linetype="dashed")
```

[image]

Comment: Normally ggplot only likes to create one color scale but you want two in this case so it's a bit tricky. See this blog on how to do that: https://www.r-bloggers.com/multiple-legends-for-the-same-aesthetic-2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using ggnewscale, first something with the same format as your data:

```
MTH = months(seq(as.Date("1910/1/1"), as.Date("1910/12/1"), "months"))
wq4 = data.frame(Year=factor(rep(2014:2018,each=12)),
Month=factor(rep(MTH,5),levels=MTH,ordered=TRUE),
Temp=sample(10:25,60,replace=TRUE))
```

Before plotting, create a dataframe for intercepts:

```
library(ggnewscale)
library(ggplot2)

intercept_DF = data.frame(y=c(5,15),label=c("Temp1","Temp2"))


ggplot(wq4) +
 geom_line(aes(x=Month,y=Temp, color = Year,group=Year)) + 
 labs(y = "Average Temperature (C)") +
 new_scale_color()+
 geom_hline(data=intercept_DF,aes(yintercept = y,col=label),linetype="dashed")+
scale_color_manual(name="Threhold",values=c("red","darkgreen"))
```

[image]

Still figuring out how to order the two legends (if possible)